# C++ boost.regex number of repetitions specified in the string

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

Suppose I wanted to create a boost.regex expression that would match strings such as

"repetitions: 5 aaaaa"
"repetitions: 3 aaa"

Is there a way to do this with boost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used boost::regex in particular, but the regular expression you're asking for is straight-forward. Looking through the boost::regex docs, it looks like you'd do something similar to this:

```
boost::regex e("repetitions:\\s+\\d\\s+[a-zA-Z]+");
```

(double slashes are so the escape sequences aren't swallowed by the compiler)

Note:
If you're also trying to validate that the first number matches the number of letter 'a', that won't work with just a regular expression. Regexes only match characters, without any clue as to what they mean, so '5' and '3' are not seen in any numerical way. Look at their docs on [Captures](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/captures.html). You'll want to get the number as a string, `lexical_cast` it to an integer, and use that to validate the `aaaaa` part.

Comment: In your regex it will match things like "repetitions: 3 rrrr", which I don't think the OP meant

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I added a note on that regard.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in my original post. I was "trying to validate that the first number matches the number of letter 'a'", as you put it. Thanks for the advice, I hadn't considered extracting the number, converting it to a string, then generating a new regex. Too bad there's not a more straightforward way to do it, though.

Comment: @Kvothe IMO there is a much more straightforward way to do it: read the number, and loop through the rest of the string while counting the repetitions.

Comment: @Fernandes The actual strings I want to analyze are more complicated - I was just trying to come up with a basic example of what I wanted.